# How to scroll beyond the top of the buffer?

Tags: scrolling

`Gzz` will go to the last line in the buffer and then scroll such that it is in the middle of the screen.

`ggzz` doesn't do this. The `zz` won't move the first line to the middle of the screen.

How can I change the behaviour of `ggzz` to be more like `Gzz` and insert blank space above the first line of the buffer so that it will be in the middle of the screen?

Comment: that is not possible.

Comment: I expected that it wouldn't be supported in vanilla vim with a command or option. I assume that most things are possible if you are willing to basically make your own plugin though; so, how could you go about achieving this? Happy for this to be a Neovim only plugin if needs be.

Comment: just use the ex command: `:$` and then scroll back again with Ctrl-B

Comment: Or go to the last line with G instead of `:$`

Comment: I think what @ChristianBrabandt means is that you’d have to modify source code to support this behavior.

Comment: There is nothing above line 1 in either Vim or Neovim so there is nothing to scroll to. Writing your own plugin won't change anything to that. Achieving your goal would require rewriting substantial parts of Vim's source code. Are you up for that?